# Get Employee_Name, Basic_Salary of TOP 2 employees with highest Basic_Salary using sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═════════╦════════════════╦
║ Emp_ID ║ EMP_Name ║ Dept_ID ║  Basic_Salary  ║  
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╬
║      1 ║ Rahul    ║       1 ║           5000 ║  
║      2 ║ Raj      ║       2 ║           3000 ║  
║      3 ║ Amit     ║       1 ║           4000 ║  
║      4 ║ Sandeep  ║       1 ║           6000 ║  
╚════════╩══════════╩═════════╩════════════════╩ 

select name,basic_sal 
from emp 
where basic_sal >=(SELECT MAX(basic_sal) 
                   FROM emp 
                   WHERE basic_sal NOT IN (SELECT MAX(basic_sal) 
                                           FROM Emp ))
```

Comment: select name,basic_sal from emp where basic_sal >=(SELECT MAX(basic_sal) FROM emp
WHERE basic_sal NOT IN (SELECT MAX(basic_sal) FROM Emp ))

Comment: You can edit your own question...(see the edit link?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: What about more than 2 employees with the same highest salary?

Comment: select top (N) basic_sal , name from emp order by basic_sal desc

Answer (score 1):

For the normal case

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM employees ORDER BY Basic_Salary DESC
```

Updated:

In the case of more than two employees who are getting top 2 salary and want to get all those employees

```
SELECT * FROM employees 
WHERE Basic_Salary IN 
(SELECT TOP 2 Basic_Salary FROM employees ORDER BY DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return.

The SELECT TOP clause can be very useful on large tables with thousands of records. Returning a large number of records can impact on performance.

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM employees ORDER BY Basic_Salary DESC
```